# Expose Grafana from Docker behind Nginx

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose, grafana

### Background

My app stack uses several Docker containers managed by `docker compose`:

- PostgreSQL at port 5433
- FastAPI (Python) backend at port 8000
- NodeJS frontend at port 8090 and exposed to 80 (via Nginx, see further)
- pgAdmin at port 5050
- Prometheus logging at port 9090
- Grafana at port 3090

See the container info returned by `docker-compose ps`:

[image]

### Docker compose config

The containers are exposed in the `docker-compose.override.yml` config as follows:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  pgadmin:
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"

  frontend:
    ports:
      - "8090:80"

  prometheus:
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

  grafana:    
    ports:
      - "3090:3090"
```

### Internal proxy config

Inside the frontend container, there's a Nginx proxy that manages the port routing inside the app stack. Its config is like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     example.com;

        gzip            on;
        gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript application/json;
        gzip_min_length 1000;

        charset                                   utf-8;     
        include                                   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        client_max_body_size                      20M;

        root                                      /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            expires                               $expires;
            index                                 index.html index.htm;
            try_files                             $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass                          http://backend:8000/;
            proxy_http_version                  1.1;
            proxy_set_header                    Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout                  1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout               1800;
        }
}
```

### Host proxy config

The host itself has a running Nginx proxy configured simply like so:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name     _;

        location / {
            proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8090/;
            proxy_set_header                    Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header                    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

### The Question

I want to be able to view the Grafana dashboard from `http://<myip>:3090` and pgAdmin from `http://<myip>:5050`, but currently 'Page Not Found (404)' is returned by the browser (without any Nginx header). When I try `http://<myip>:3000` (seeing that Grafana also runs at 3000, although I explicitly set it to 3090), I get the same error.

At the same time, I can somehow access Prometheus at `http://<myip>:9090`... But not Grafana or pgAdmin. What did I miss out?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- ideally, a complete `docker-compose.yaml` that we can copy and run locally to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: A runnable example is not feasible, since the container docker files entail lots of dependencies like a python venv with packages, NodeJS installation etc etc. The problem is clearly somewhere in the Nginx configs.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the "minimal" part means in [mcve]; a runnable example is *absolutely* possible, and only needs to contains the services you're asking about in this question. If you were to expand your existing example you'd be all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly confused about your goals; your title is "Expose Grafana from Docker behind Nginx", but it looks like you're planning to access Grafana in a way that *bypasses* nginx by publishing the port on the host and accessing it directly.

An immediate problem I see here is this:

```
  grafana:
    ports:
      - "3090:3090"
```

Grafana listens on port 3000 by default; absent explicit configuration to the contrary, if you want to expose Grafana on *host* port 3090 you would write:

```
  grafana:
    ports:
      - "3090:3000"
```

Similarly, pgadmin listens on port 80, so unless you are explicit setting `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT`, you would write:

```
  pgadmin:
      ports:
        - "5050:80"
```

Putting that all together, the following `docker-compose.yaml` would expose:

- Prometheus on port 9090
- Grafana on port 3090
- Pgadmin on port 5050

Postgres is not exposed on the host (but would be available for use by other services in your compose).

```
volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: docker.io/prom/prometheus:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  grafana:
    image: docker.io/grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - 3090:3000

  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "secret"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX: "1"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - 5050:80
```

This is a runnable example -- you can copy and paste it locally and run `docker compose up`; it has no dependencies on local files.

---

Note that you *could* remove the port publishing from all of the above services, and instead add an nginx proxy that would publish a single port, and then access the services at specific paths (like `http://localhost:8090/prometheus/`, `http://localhost:8090/grafana/`, `http://localhost:8090/pgadmin/`, etc).

That configuration might look like this:

```
volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: docker.io/prom/prometheus:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      - '--web.external-url=/prometheus/'

  grafana:
    image: docker.io/grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    environment:
        GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/"
        GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: "true"

  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "secret"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX: "1"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret

  nginx:
    image: docker.io/nginx:mainline
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 8090:80
```

Where `nginx/default.conf` looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name     localhost;

  location /grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://grafana:3000/;
  }

  location /prometheus/ {
    proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/prometheus/;
  }

  location /pgadmin/ {
    proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80/;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I was indeed wrong in my port forwarding. Publishing as you suggested solved the problem. However, the second option with location mapping still doesn't work out for me. Do I need also to change my HOST nginx config? I changed my INTERNAL nginx config in the container as you suggested, but I can't access those services from outside.

Comment: With the configuration I show here, we're exposing the containerized nginx on host port 8090. Anybody who can access port 8090 on the host can access the services. The same holds true for the published ports in the earlier example. Note that I am *not* running an additional nginx on the host, so perhaps remove that to simplify things and see what behavior you get.

Comment: The additional (host) nginx is not removable, since it is inbuilt in the VPS I use (does other port forwarding stuff). I've tried adding the configs you suggest to this external nginx (/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf), but it doesn't work. Also, I've tried leaving these server configs in the container nginx and adding simple reverse proxies to the external one (like proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/prometheus) but to no avail.

Comment: The configuration shown here seems to work just fine if I start an additional nginx proxy on the host, using the exact configuration you show in your question. A request for `http://localhost/prometheus` first goes to the host nginx, which due to the `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/` for `location /` passes it to `http://127.0.0.1:8090/prometheus`, which is handled by the containerized proxy, which passes it to the prometheus container.

Comment: Oh well, I may have confused something. Many thanks for helping!